# Insert class if true

Tags: php, class, if-statement

How do I insert a class with php if something is true? Here's my best guess so far:

```
<div class="<?php
  if($this->step==2){
    somehow set the name of the class
  } ?>">
```

Comment: The logic is right, make sure to separate `div` and `class`, and echo out the class name inside `if`

Comment: Just as a point of interest, I'd question where you are generating this output that `$this->step` is available. `$this` is only available from inside a class.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're close; what you can do is echo the class with PHP.

```
<!-- Either try this... -->
<div class="<?php if($this->step === 2) { echo 'twostep'; } ?>"></div>

<!-- ...or this -->
<div class="<?=$this->step === 2 ? 'twostep' : 'notwostep'?>"></div>
```

Comment: As a point of clarification, I prefer using the identical comparison operator (`===`), since the number 2 may mean something different than the character 2.

Comment: that is strage, by me is only the first way functional
`class="<?php if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'smth')) echo 'active'?>"`

Comment: @A.Volg, if the second version isn't working for you, then you're working with a very old version of PHP (PHP 5.3 or lower) that has short_tags turned off; as of 5.4 (which was EOL'd five years ago), `<?= ?>` is available regardless of the short_tags setting. Also, be careful; `strpos` returns a falsy value (0) if the needle string is found in the first position of the haystack!

Answer (score 2):

Close:

```
<div class="<?php if($this->step==2){ echo "classA"; } ?>
```

Here's an example

```
<div class="<?php if($active) { echo "link_active"; } ?>
```

**How does this work**

Basically, all you need is to print out the class between the `class=" "` and the `echo` in PHP does just that. So you simply do `echo "class_name`. You can also use the PHP shorthand like `<?= php code here ?>`

Answer (score 1):

Simply echo the class name. For example

```
<div class="<?php if($this->step == 2) echo 'step-2'; ?>"></div>
```

Also, brackets are optional for one liners. In fact, you could use short hand like this:

```
<div class="<?php echo $this->step == 2? 'step-2' : ''; ?>"></div>
```