# Want to hide the div if sql value is 0 php css

Tags: php, html, css

I want to hide the div if the value is 1 and show it when value is 0.
my code is below.

```
<?php 
    $sqlN ="select count(MantisId) as val from issue_type where MantisId ='".$id."'";
    $resultN = $conn->query($sqlN);
    //`status`
            
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultN,MYSQLI_ASSOC);


    //get row

    $Val=$row['val'] ??'';
    if($Val==1){
        echo "
        <style>
            div.hidden {
                display: none;
            }
        </style>";

    } else if($Val==0){
        
         echo "
         <style>
            div.hidden {
                display: inline;
            }
         </style>";
    }
?>
                                    
                
                                        
            
<form method="post" action="" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <div class="row">
    
        <div class="col-sm-2 hidden">
            <div class="form-group">
                
                <select class="form-control" id="iss_type" name="iss_type">
                    <option value="">-Error Type-</option>
                    <option value="Modification">Modification</option>
                    <option value="Development">Development</option>
                    <option value="Server_Issue">Server Issue</option>
                    <option value="System_Issue">System Issue</option>
      
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can't you instead echo the div if the condition is true?

Comment: tried without echo but i can't get my output as wish

Answer (score 0):

With your current method, you can add the `css` for **hidden** and **inline**, and what you do, is add the class **hidden** if `$Val==1`, and add the class **inline** otherwise.

```
<style>
   div.hidden {
      display: none;
   }
   div.inline{
      display: inline;
   }
</style>
```

```
<div class="col-sm-2 <?php if($Val==1)echo 'hidden'; else echo 'inline'; ?>"  >
     <div class="form-group">    
          <select class="form-control" id="iss_type" name="iss_type">
                 <option value="">-Error Type-</option>
                 <option value="Modification">Modification</option>
                 <option value="Development">Development</option>
                 <option value="Server_Issue">Server Issue</option>
                 <option value="System_Issue">System Issue</option> 
           </select>
      </div>
</div>
```

Here's how the code should look like:

```
<?php $sqlN ="select count(MantisId) as val from issue_type where MantisId ='".$id."'"; 
// $resultN = $conn->query($sqlN); 
//status $row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultN,MYSQLI_ASSOC); $Val=$row['val'] ??''; 
$Val = 0;
?> 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style> div.hidden { display: none; } div.inline{ display: inline; } </style> 
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="" enctype='multipart/form-data'> 
        <div class="row"> 
            <div class="col-sm-2 <?php if($Val==1)echo 'hidden'; else echo 'inline'; ?>">   
                <select>
                    <option value="">-Error Type-</option>
                    <option value="Modification">Modification</option>
                    <option value="Development">Development</option>
                    <option value="Server_Issue">Server Issue</option>
                    <option value="System_Issue">System Issue</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: checked your code but it is visible both 0,1

Comment: Hi @ChathuRaaksha, I tried it and it hides the div. Have you added both inline and hidden class?

Comment: <style>
           div.hidden {
           display: none;
           }
           div.inline{
           display: inline;
           }
</style> <?php $sqlN ="select count(MantisId) as val from issue_type where MantisId ='".$id."'";
           $resultN = $conn->query($sqlN);
           //`status`
             
           $row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultN,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
          $Val=$row['val'] ??'';
  ?>
           <form method="post" action="" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
      <div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-2 <?php if($Val==1)echo 'hidden'; else echo 'inline'; ?>">

Comment: @ChathuRaaksha Nothing is wrong, try changing the value of `$Val` manually and check the result. I've updated my answer and you can try to copy paste and test the code. Cheers!

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18265058/insert-class-if-true/18265069) out to add class when php `$var` is true.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to use PHP to hide the div, you can instead use it to echo the div itself when the condition is true:

```html
<form method="post" action="" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<?php
if ($Val == 1) {

    echo '<div class="row">'; //etc

}
?>
```

Note that the PHP code I've written is **after** the `form` tag, so that the echoed content is in the correct place.